# Center a Model3D on ViewPort3D

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe6, firemonkey-fm3

There seems to be a problem with `Model3D` dimentions ... you can set components width and height to  1 and real model stays out of bounds, but still there, with same original size (defined by scale). How can you center a model on `ViewPort` then?

Comment: You should *always* add the **delphi** tag to your Delphi related questions. If you ever wonder about low attention to your question, that is the reason. (the same with all tags containing a special version)

Comment: @FlashThunder did you ever figure out how to centre the model?

Comment: @RickWheeler nope :/